# Optimizing difficulty with a level generator using Clingo

Tags: logic-programming, answer-set-programming, clingo

I’m making a puzzle level generator (sokoban) using Clingo and got stuck trying to create levels with a specific move limit. The idea is to use the move limit to control difficulty of a level. This is how I’ve created the generator:

1. Specify rules for a valid looking level (all walkable tiles are connected, correct ampunt of pushable barrels and target platforms, etc.)
2. Specify rules for moving around and pushing barrels.
3. Specify winning conditions.

My first iteration was to simply require that a level is solvable in N moves by requiring that winning conditions are met in `0..N` moves. This resulted in valid levels but there was no control over the difficulty.

My second iteration was to minimize the moves required for a winning condition to be met. This resulted in levels that are completed in a single move.

My third iteration was to state that a level could not be completed in less than M moves. This resulted in the logic doing unnecessary moves just to reach the minimum, there was still no meaningful control over difficulty.

My fourth iteration was to prevent the same game state from reoccurring to avoid unnecessary ”filler” moves, but this still resulted in the logic solving the levels in very unoptimally just to reach the minimum requirement.

Now I don’t really know what to do. I think what I want to do is maximize the minimum required amount of moves (up to a limit), but I’m not sure if that makes any sense. Preferrably I’d like to be able to state that the minimum amount of moves for completing this level should be `M`.

How should this problem be approached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to put it in other terms: you are searching for a puzzle that can be solved in `N` moves but solving it in `N-1` would return unsatisfiable. Those two parts state complimentary problems ("Find at least one" vs. "Find none/all") and are difficult to put in one program and the combination raises the problem complexity (see [polynomial hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy)). Here three suggestions to solve it via enumeration:

1. Enumeration and difference: For `N` and `N-1` enumerate all answers. A puzzle is solvable in exactly `N` steps, when it appears for `N` but not for `N-1`. This requires some sort of post processing, like a script or neat text editing.
2. Enumeration and unsatisfiable: In a script enumerate all answer sets one by one for the current `N`. For the current puzzle, try to solve it for `N-1`: if it returns `0` answers, you have your puzzle. This requires data-handling of some form, I would suggest using python.
3. Enumeration avoiding doubles: In a script, for `N-1` generate all answer sets. Transform each answer set into a constraint and add it to the program. Example: the tiles `m(1..4,l). m(1..4,r)` define your puzzle in general, your current answer set is `m(1,l). m(2,l). m(3,r).`, add the following constraint to avoid generating this puzzle again. Afterwards solve the updated program for `N`.

   `:- m(1,l), m(2,l), m(3,r), not m(1,r), not m(2,r), not m(3,l), not m(4,l), not m(4,r).`

As you might see all three methods would solve your problem but require additional effort outside of clingo.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I can see the problem and post-processing also occured to me, I was just not sure if it was necessary. I trust you’re right that it is indeed required. I will continue in that direction!